# What is a "slender delta" wing?

Tags: terminology, delta-wing

I am curious about delta wings. I read some articles and found the term "slender delta". Please help me to understand this term.

Answer (score 4):

A slender delta wing is a delta with low aspect ratio.

The use I have seen is in the study of [vortex lift](http://www.ltas-aea.ulg.ac.be/cms/uploads/Expaero04.pdf), which is present at high angles of attack.

[What is vortex lift?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21069/what-is-vortex-lift)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Slender wing having a very high sweep angle which typically Λ>65°.
The non-slender wing is having low to moderately swept (35°–55°) wing planforms.

[image]